# Create a list of all intersection points of a rectangle with a given line

Tags: java, line, point, rectangles, intersect

So I have a finished working function that finds intersection points and also a rectangle class.
I want to create a list of all those points.

Can you suggest me how to do it?
Thanks.

```
public class Rectangle {

private double width;
private double height;
private Point upperLeft;

// Create a new rectangle with location and width/height.
public Rectangle(Point upperLeft, double width, double height){
    this.upperLeft = upperLeft;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height
}

// Return a (possibly empty) List of intersection points
// with the specified line.
public java.util.List<Point> intersectionPoints(Line line){
    //**I don't know
}
```

}

I was thinking about something like
creating 2 arrays of 4.

```
Line[] rectLines = new Line[4];
    Point[] IntersectionPoints = new Point[4];
```

then create 4 lines based on the rectangle corners and add them to the array.

```
rectLines[0] = new Line(rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY());
    rectLines[1] = new Line(rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY(), rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getHeight());
    rectLines[2] = new Line(rect.getUpperLeft().getX(), rect.getHeight(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
    rectLines[3] = new Line(rect.getWidth(), rect.getUpperLeft().getY(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
```

then run a loop that adds that uses my intersection finder function and finds the points and adds them to the array of the points.

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if (intersectionWith(rectLines[i]) != null)
            IntersectionPoints[i] = intersectionWith(rectLines[i]);}
```

The "**intersectionWith**" function returns NULL if there is no intersection point, ad returns the point if there is a point.

But now what? How can I make it a list?
Do you think it's smart to define the points' array size as 4 although I don't really know if it's gonna be 0,1,2,3 or 4? And then what will happen to the unused slots in the array?

p.s
what happens if the line goes through a corner? it means it would have 2 intersection points because it will intersect with 2 rectangle sides.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using a List, you can just use the add method

Comment: What does `intersectionWith()` do if two lines do not intersect (they are parallel) or if they have infinite intersection points (they lie on top of each other)?

Comment: I suggest that you read a tutorial about how to create a `List` and add elements to it. This is a pretty fundamental thing in Java and there are a lot of tutorials about it. For example, Oracle has one here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I have added the reply  to the main topic. It returns a NULL.

Comment: @DimaCiun Thanks for editing your question to add the details I asked for. I think that the different cases for intersection are a minor detail to your main question. You need to find a tutorial to learn about lists in Java. The link I gave is the official one from Oracle, but there are others out there that can get you started.